# Powershell script to run SQL script file to alter database table without starting MS SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a PowerShell script that will run MS SQL scripts that will update a SQL Server database. The SQL scripts will be saved in a specific folder and after running the PowerShell, it should run the scripts without starting Management Studio.

I have a PowerShell command that is able to start and fire `sqlcmd` in PowerShell, but what is letting me down is that when I use the `Invoke-item` function of PowerShell, it is starting Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. What I want is to pass login credentials in the script and run the SQL scripts without starting SQL Server Management Studio.

```
PS C:\Users\Admin> $SqlServer = "localhost"
PS C:\Users\Admin> $SqlDBName = "Test"
PS C:\Users\Admin> $SqlConnection =New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
PS C:\Users\Admin> $SqlConnection.ConnectionString ="Server = $SqlServer; Database =$SqlDBName; User id ='**'; password ='**'"
PS C:\Users\Admin> Invoke-Item 'D:\MSSQLScripts\AlterTable.sql'
```

AlterTable.sql is like this

```
use Test
Alter table employee
add Dateofjoining date;
select * from  Employee
```

So what is happening is that PowerShell is firing the `AlterTable.sql` script and starts Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio login in page. I want this to be seamless - no other human involvement. The login page must not appear at all. The reason of passing credentials in the `SqlConnection` string is to avoid this.It should just alter the db and that everything users should check the log file.

Comment: Check out the PowerShell [invoke-sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) cmdlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by substituting Get-Content with **Invoke-Sqlcmd**. With **Invoke-Sqlcmd**, I am able to run sql scripts without firing Microsoft SQL Management Studio. So in this case I am using ***Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile (file path)*** and it is executing the script.

Answer (score 0):

Read the script into a string, pass it to an [`SqlCommand` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netframework-4.8) and execute:

```
$SqlScript = Get-Content D:\MSSQLScripts\AlterTable.sql -Raw
$SqlCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCommand.CommandText = $SqlScript
$SqlCommand.Connection = $SqlConnection
[void]$SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: I thought about it but then I considered a situation where sql operation are many ut I think this can also help to have a better log file where I can also pass sql related errors. Thanks I will give a go at this.